# How do you deal with CA2000 (Dispose of IDisposable Objects) when the objects are placed in a Dependency Injection container?

Tags: singleton, stylecop, ca2000

According to Microsoft, the best practice for an HttpClient is to maintain a singleton version of an HttpClient (paraphrasing, but that's the upshot.  Don't dispose of it immediately).  My own testing has show that there are definite advantages to a single instance when doing massive Http operations over recreating an HttpClient for every message.  So, naturally, it makes sense to place the HttpClient in a DI container.

```
    // Initialize the HTTP client.
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost");
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(httpClient);
```

The problem is that I'm getting warnings from StyleCop: **CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope.**  Obviously I can suppress, but this bothers me because there are other IDisposable objects that may want to be put in the DI container.  Is this warning valid when using a DI pattern?  Are there any tricks to dealing with it?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue , same thoughts.

What you can do is assign it to a field

eg this.httpClient = new HttpClient();

this is probably not a bad idea anyway for singletons so their is a clear owner outside IOC  .